# To include '#' in regex of words around certain words

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I want to get the output to determine 3 words that are near a certain word. 
For this example, the word will be to return 3 words from the left and 3 words from the right around "to".

```
import re 
sentence="#allows us to be free from the place"

key= "to"

left=[]
right=[]
m = re.search(r'((?:\w+\W+){,3})'+key+'\W+((?:\w+\W+){,3})',sentence)

if m:
    l = [ x.strip().split() for x in m.groups()]

    #l= two arrays of left and right
left, right = l[0], l[1]
print left, right
```

Output:

```
['allows', 'us'] ['be', 'free', 'from']
```

As you can see from the output, '#' symbol was not included.
Expected output:

```
['#allows', 'us'] ['be', 'free', 'from']
```

Note:
Since there are only a maximum of 2 words around "to", it will return both words although the regex is for 3 words

In some cases, the key might be more than one word

What seems to be the problem, and how to solve it? Thank you

Comment: \w probably matches word-characters, and # is not one.  Try replacing `\w+` with `#?\w+` in your regular expression? (an optional # before the sequence of word characters...)

Comment: I see, thank you so much. It helped to solve the problem.and thank you for your explanation

Comment: It's better form to use a character class. `m = re.search(r'((?:[#\w]+\s?){,3})' + key + r'\s?((?:[#\w]+\s?){,3})', sentence)
`

Answer (score 0):

No need to do this with regex. You can use a [list slice](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html?highlight=slice#slicings).

```
sentence = '#allows us to be free from the place'
search_word = 'to'
context = 3

words = sentence.split()

try:
    word_index = words.index(search_word)
    start = max(0, word_index - context)
    stop = min(word_index + 1 + context, len(words))
    context_words = words[start:stop]
    print(context_words)
except ValueError:
    print('search_word not in the sentence')
```

prints

```
['#allows', 'us', 'to', 'be', 'free', 'from']
```

Use two slices if you want separate "before" and "after" lists.